# What is the exact meaning of the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

I am not English native speaker, I am Italian.

I couldn't understand, I am confused.

What is the exact meaning of the following sentence in simple English?

> "Later, a member of the exchange was not required to be a member of
>   the clearinghouse if it could arrange for a clearinghouse member to
>   assume responsibility for the nonmember’s obligations to the
>   clearinghouse."

Which one is "to assume responsibility for obligations": a clearinghouse member or a member of the exchange?

---

> Only in 1925 did the CBOT form the Board of Trade Clearing Corporation
>   (BOTCC), a true CCP that became the counterparty to all transactions
>   on the exchange. With the creation of BOTCC, members of the exchange
>   were required to purchase shares in the clearinghouse, and only the
>   member shareholders were permitted to use the facility. **(Later, a
>   member of the exchange was not required to be a member of the
>   clearinghouse if it could arrange for a clearinghouse member to
>   assume responsibility for the nonmember’s obligations to the
>   clearinghouse.)**
>
> Members were also required to post their margin deposits with the
>   clearinghouse. In the event of a member’s default, the clearinghouse
>   would take responsibility for settling the defaulting member’s trades.

Comment: In English, we always capitalize proper nouns like _English._ We also _always_ capitalize the first word of a sentence, and the first person singular pronoun. This should be at least as important as, and certainly more basic than, an understanding of the phrase _"to assume responsibility for obligations"._

Comment: The Exchange member was not required to be a member of the Clearinghouse if it could arrange for a proxy to discharge its obligations to the Clearinghouse; the proxy had to be a member of the Clearinghouse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any ambiguity here, the key phrase is

> a clearing house member to assume responsibility

It is the Clearing House Member that is assuming responsibility on behalf of the Member of the Exchange.